# how to upload files from android internal storage and informations to php-mysql server using AsyncTask method?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask, upload

I'm trying to wright some codes to upload a file and a picture and some information about them together but my try is not working and always `doInBackground` returns empty result .

here is my try:

```
public class RegBookActivity extends Activity {

        private static final int SELECT_FILE_DIALOG = 1;
        private static final int SELECT_IMAGE_DIALOG = 302;
        String sourceFileUri, sourceImgUri;
        String[] sp1;
        TextView uptxt, pathfiletxt, pathpictxt, regbookerrtxt;
        Button chfilebtn, chpicbtn, regbookbtn;
        EditText namketabedt, nevisandeedt, hajmedt;
        ImageView upimage;
        Spinner s1;
        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        private Uri getUri() {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if(!state.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                return MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            return MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, result);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE_DIALOG) {
                    if (null == result) return;
                    Uri data = result.getData();

                    if(data.getLastPathSegment().endsWith("pdf") || data.getLastPathSegment().endsWith("mp3")){
                        sourceFileUri = data.getPath();
                        SharedPreferences upload = getSharedPreferences("uploadPrefs", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor setedt = upload.edit();
                        setedt.putString("filepath", data.getPath());
                        setedt.commit();
                        pathfiletxt.setText(upload.getString("filepath", "").toString());
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(RegBookActivity.this, "نوع فایل انتخابی قابل قبول نیست", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                    }               

            }
                if(requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE_DIALOG){
                    if (null == result) return;
                    try {
                        Uri originalUri = result.getData();


                        String pathsegment[] = originalUri.getLastPathSegment().split(":");
                        String id = pathsegment[0];
                        final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                        final String imageOrderBy = null;

                        Uri uri = getUri();
                        Cursor imageCursor = RegBookActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, imageColumns,
                                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=" + id, null, null);

                        if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            String value = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                            if(value.contains("jpg") || value.contains("png")){
                                sourceImgUri = value;
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(value);
                                upimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                SharedPreferences upload = getSharedPreferences("uploadPrefs", 0);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor setedt = upload.edit();
                                setedt.putString("picpath", value);
                                setedt.commit();
                                pathpictxt.setText(upload.getString("picpath", "").toString());
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(RegBookActivity.this, "نوع فایل انتخابی قابل قبول نیست", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                            } 
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegBookActivity.this, "نوع فایل انتخابی قابل قبول نیست", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg_book);

            namketabedt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            nevisandeedt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            hajmedt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            chfilebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_chosfile);
            chpicbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_chospic);
            regbookbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            uptxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_uplodkonande);
            regbookerrtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_regbookerr);
            pathfiletxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_pathfile);
            pathpictxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_pathpic);
            upimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


            sp1=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.books);
            s1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_mozoo);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sp1);
            s1.setAdapter(adapter1);

            chfilebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("audio/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "فایل مورد نظر خود را انتخاب کنید:"), SELECT_FILE_DIALOG);
                }
            });

            chpicbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "فایل مورد نظر خود را انتخاب کنید:"), SELECT_IMAGE_DIALOG);
                }

            });

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("userPrefs", 0);
            uptxt.setText(settings.getString("username", "").toString());

            regbookbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (( !namketabedt.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !nevisandeedt.getText().toString().equals("")) 
                        && ( !hajmedt.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !uptxt.getText().toString().equals("")) 
                        && ( !s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")) 
                        && ( !pathfiletxt.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !pathpictxt.getText().toString().equals(""))
                            ){
                               new regbook().execute();
                        } else{
                            regbookerrtxt.setText("یکی یا چندتا از فیلدهای موجود خالی است");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

and here is my uploading files class in RegBookActivity:

```
private class regbook extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {


        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegBookActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("درحال آپلود فایل، لطفا منتظر بمانيد...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        public String upload(String suri)
        {
            int count;  
            File sourceFile = new File(suri);

            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
                pDialog.dismiss(); 
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegBookActivity.this)
                .setTitle("خطا در آپلود فایل")
                .setMessage("فایل انتخابی وجود ندارد!");
                builder.create().show();
            }
            else{
                try{
//                    URL url = new URL(JSONCommands.firstURL + "services.php?op=insertBook"); 
//                    HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//                  conection.connect();
                    URL url = new URL(JSONCommands.firstURL + "services.php?op=insertBook");
                    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                    conection.connect();

//                  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

//                  dos = new DataOutputStream(conection.getOutputStream());
                    OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(conection.getOutputStream());
                 // create a buffer of  maximum size
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    long total = 0;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                        //publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                        // writing data to file
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    // flushing output
                    output.flush();

                    // closing streams
                    output.close();
                    input.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... response) { 
            final String bookfilename = sourceFileUri.substring(sourceFileUri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            final String bookimgname = sourceImgUri.substring(sourceImgUri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            MainActivity.params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("namketab", namketabedt.getText().toString()));
            MainActivity.params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nevisande", nevisandeedt.getText().toString()));
            MainActivity.params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mozoo", s1.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            MainActivity.params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hajm", hajmedt.getText().toString()));
            MainActivity.params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uplodkonande", uptxt.getText().toString()));
            MainActivity.params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fileketab", bookfilename));
            upload(sourceFileUri);
            MainActivity.params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tasvir", bookimgname));
            upload(sourceImgUri);
            ArrayList<String>  res = JSONCommands.insertData(MainActivity.params,"insertBook");
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> res) {
            if (res.isEmpty()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegBookActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("خطا در برقراری ارتباط با سرور")
                        .setMessage("ثبت کتاب ناموفق :( اتصالات را بررسی کنید.");
                builder.create().show();

            }else if (res.get(0).equals("book stored successfully")) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    regbookerrtxt.setText("");
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegBookActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("آپلود کتاب با موفقیت انجام شد")
                    .setMessage("و پس از تایید به نمایش گذاشته خواهد شد. از آپلود شما سپاس‌گذاریم.");
                    builder.create().show();
             }else if (res.get(0).equals("book pic failed to store")){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    regbookerrtxt.setText("ذخیره‌ی عکس کتاب ناموفق");
             }else if (res.get(0).equals("book file failed to store")){
                 pDialog.dismiss();
                 regbookerrtxt.setText("ذخیره‌ی فایل کتاب ناموفق");
             }else{
                 pDialog.dismiss();
                 regbookerrtxt.setText("ذخیره‌ی  کتاب ناموفق");
              }

       }
    }
```

and this is my server side php code:

```
function insertBook(){
    $con = db_connect();
    $response = array();

        $namketab = $_REQUEST['namketab'];
        $nevisande = $_REQUEST['nevisande'];
        $mozoo = $_REQUEST['mozoo'];
        $uplodkonande = $_REQUEST['uplodkonande'];
        $hajm = $_REQUEST['hajm'];

        $tasvir = "images/";
        $tasvir = $tasvir . basename( $_FILES['tasvir']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tasvir']['tmp_name'], $tasvir)) {
        empty($response);
      }else{
        $response[] = "book pic failed to store";
      }
      $tasvir = str_replace(' ', '%20', $tasvir);

        $fileketab = "uploads/";
        $fileketab = $fileketab . basename( $_FILES['fileketab']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileketab']['tmp_name'], $fileketab)) {
        empty($response);
      }else{
        $response[] = "book file failed to store";
      }
       $fileketab = str_replace(' ', '%20', $fileketab);

    if(empty($response)){
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tbl_books (namketab, nevisande, mozoo, uplodkonande, tasvir, fileketab, hajm, status) 
                            VALUES ('$namketab', '$nevisande', '$mozoo', '$uplodkonande', '$tasvir', '$fileketab', '$hajm', 'uploaded')");
        $response[] = "book stored successfully";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

`insertData()` function:

```
public static final String firstURL = "http://192.168.152.1/ketabha/";
    private static final String URL = firstURL + "services.php?op=";

    public static ArrayList<String> insertData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> params, String string) {
        String result = JSONParser.readURL(URL + string, params);
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("LOG", result);
                JSONArray errors = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < errors.length(); i++) {
                    ret.add(errors.getString(i));
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

is there any one can help me with this problem and help me to understand better?!

Comment: If res was null and returned by doInBackground then in onPostExecute you would have a NullPointerException on statement `if (res.isEmpty())`. Now have you?

Comment: upload() is not reading the response of the server. What is insertData() doing? So it returns null. insertData does know nothing of the POST result.

Comment: @greenapps no no I mean res is empty. doInBackground returns always empty. I edited my Question with insertData() function. take a look at it. thank you.

Comment: Please post complete insertData function. We want to see the used parameters too.

Comment: Sorry i see now that it is complete.

Comment: `upload a file and a picture and some information about them together`. No. You are not doing that together but one for one in one asynctask. You try to upload two files. But upload() uses the same url for it without indication of file type or name. Then you sent information to another url. The upload() function does not check response of server so is pretty useless. You use AlertBuilder there but that will let your app crash.